# Moving the location of the cloud console in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-shell

I have the .cloudconsole file in a file share I no longer want it. I can't seem to find a way to change where the cloud console launches from. I want the cloud shell and "img" files in another file share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just delete the share, or the entire storage account, and next time you want to use cloud shell, it will prompt you to create a new location.

**EDIT**

Turns out you can just execute `clouddrive unmount` in the console. You'll be prompted to set up a new storage configuration.

https://blog.olandese.nl/2017/09/07/mount-your-azure-cloud-shell-to-another-storage-account/

[image]

Comment: I am not able to delete that fileshare as there are important services running off it. know of any other solution?